# Specify columns classes using sparklyr

Tags: r, csv, hadoop, import, sparklyr

I am trying to use the 'columns' argument of the 'spark_read_csv()' function. I am trying to import a csv file from hdfs using sparklyr and I would like to know how it is possible to specify a single variable class or all variables classes.

```
require(sparklyr)
named_vct_colclasses <- c("character", "integer", "integer")
db_in <- spark_read_csv(sc, "spark_tbl_name", "path_to_file", 
                        infer_schema = FALSE,
                        columns = named_vct_colclasses)
```

The csv is imported correctly but I cannot impose the column classes.

I have tried using a named vector but it didn't work as well.
This is the usual read.csv command which I would like to reproduce using spark_read_csv()

```
read.csv("path_to_file", colClasses = c("character", rep("integer", 2))
```

or

```
 read.csv("path_to_file", colClasses = c("var_name" = "character"))
```

Thanks

Comment: I believe it needs to be a named vector, alas `names(named_vct_colclasses) <- vector_of_colnames`

Comment: I've tried but it seems to not be sufficient. I've also searched throughout the github page but I haven't found an example

Answer (score 0):

I Know this is a bit late, but using a named vector or list works. See example code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(sparklyr)


sc <- spark_connect(master='local', version='2.0.2')

iris_tbl<-copy_to(sc,iris)
spark_write_csv(iris_tbl,"iris.csv")
columns<-c("numeric","numeric","numeric","numeric","character")
names(columns)<-colnames(iris)
spark_read_csv(sc,"iris","iris.csv",infer_schema = FALSE,columns = columns)
```

PS. make sure that the column names are exactly as in CSV, e.g. column names are changed from '.' delimited to '_' delimited when writing to CSV.

```
> colnames(iris)
[1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Species"     
> colnames(iris_tbl)
[1] "Sepal_Length" "Sepal_Width"  "Petal_Length" "Petal_Width"  "Species"
```